# vue 2.3 AJAX data binding not updating

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

After a successful ajax call the data rendered on the page is not updating. It is remaining empty / null.

It seems that I am missing how to connect the data returned as a front end variable and the dynamically / live rendered html elements.

Here is the relevant code snippets for context. Is it clear from this what is missing / incorrect?

**Javascript**

```
page = new Vue({

  el: "#container",

  data: {
    option_id: null,
    option_name: null
  },

  created:function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajax_methods/get_option',
      success: function (ajax_data) {

        self = this;

        self.option_id = ajax_data.option_id;        
        self.option_name = ajax_data.option_name;

      },
      error: function (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })

  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.3"></script>
<div id="container">

  <p>{{ option_name }}</p>

    <button v-on:click="send_option()"
      type="button"
      id="left_button"
      name="left_button"
      v-bind:value="option_id">

</div>
```

**Checking AJAX success**

When entering the following in the console, non null values come back as expected:

- self.option_id
- self.option_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first,  if that is the exact code, then `self` I don't think is initialized.  Use `var self = this` or `let self = this`

But mainly, you need to define `self` outside of the ajax call.  In javascript the `this` keyword refers to the calling object.  directly inside of the `created()` function, it's the Vue instance.  However, `this` will NOT refer to the Vue instance once inside the ajax callback.

[Understand JavaScript’s “this” With Clarity, and Master It](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

```
created:function() {

   var self = this    
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajax_methods/get_option',
      success: function (ajax_data) {

        self.option_id = ajax_data.option_id;        
        self.option_name = ajax_data.option_name;

      },
      error: function (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to capture `this` *outside* the callback.

```
created: function(){

    const self = this;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajax_methods/get_option',
      success: function (ajax_data) {

        self.option_id = ajax_data.option_id;        
        self.option_name = ajax_data.option_name;

      },
      error: function (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })
}
```